# Minhag saying Shema after Aleinu

Tags: minhag, tefilla, chasidut-hasidism, shema

Shalom!
I heard some [Biala chassidim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biala_%28Hasidic_dynasty%29) saying the posuk of Shema Israel after completing the prayer of Aleinu Leshabeyach.
Where does that tradition come from?

Comment: This is also done in [tag:nusach-edot-hammizrach].

Answer (score 1):

In my סידור אוצר  התפלות, the commentary of the עיון תפלה says that in the מחזור בני רומא the Shema is said after completing the prayer of Aleinu Leshabeyach.